# Testing private server using Browserstack and FireFox

Tags: firefox, browserstack

Purportedly Browserstack can be used to do "local testing". When using Chrome or FireFox this default supported and should work transparently.

There is not a lof of documentation on how this should work so this makes me wonder if this is done in practice.

For example, I have a private website that I can only reach using the proxy server that is also used to access public URL's. I think that Browserstack considers this website public somehow and so it fails to reach this website.

Also I noticed - since installing the Browserstack extension - FireFox is crashing like there is no tomorrow.

This also makes me wonder how well this works in practice. I can't imagine any serious testing being done with combination of FireFox/Browserstack and local testing.

Is Browserstack used in practice for testing private servers? How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently browserstack doesn't support local testing via extension when your local testing server is behind a proxy.

In this case you need to use Browserstack binary with parameters

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key <your_key> --proxy-host <proxy_host> --proxy-port <proxy_port>
```

Binary can be used to do Live testing on safari/IE or to run automate tests.

If you are facing issues while using your extension (i.e. firefox crashing) . I would recommend you to contact support @browserstack.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the following command line

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key ******* --proxy-host 10.122.*.*\ 
--proxy-port 3128 --local-proxy-host 10.122.*.*\
--local-proxy-port 3128  --only devops.ok,443,1
```

Notice there are two entries for the proxy server `proxy-host` and `local-proxy-host`. The first is used to create the tunnel to browserstack.com. The second one `local-proxy-host` tells browserstack to also use the proxy server to connect to my internal server `devops.ok`.

`devops.ok,443,1` is hostname and port, the `1` is for https.